# plugins sublime

Tags: sublime-text-2

Galera estou com um problema chato no sublime, instalei o plugin  [reindent_on_save](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Reindent%20on%20save) porém estou tendo um problema quando pego um cód não tão bem identado. Tentei tirar esse plugin diretamente na pasta porém ele volta toda vez que fecho e abro o sublime. Como faço para deletar de vez esse plugin alguém poderia me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem o Package Manager:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. $> Package Control: Remove Package
3. Selecione o pacote que queira remover e confirme.